# Combining duplicate lines and add quantity

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, rows

I am using the below lines of code. Instead of me having to highlight the range.  Is there a code that can select my data range? I'm getting stuck on the bolded line of code. I want the range to be selected automatically.

```
Sub MyEnterEvent()

   Set R = Application.Selection
    **Set R = Application.InputBox("select one Range:", "CombineDuplicateRowsAndSum", R.Address, Type:=8)**
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr = R.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 3)
    Next
    R.ClearContents
    R.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
    R.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what happens if you remove that line and run it? or what's the idea with the initial selection?

Comment: `Set r = ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B20:C40")`  would select the range "B20:C40", whenever you write the line `r.Select`. Is this what you are after?

Comment: I posted an answer to your question - perhaps you'd be so good as to let me know if it works?

Comment: @ Vityata i'm getting an error using that code.  The range will change as data is entered. So, I need add something like "Used.Range".

Comment: @ SJR sorry, I don't see your answer.